# Jquery-ui .dialog() function gives Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use Jquery-ui .dialog() method. Here is my function for this :

```
jsPlumb.bind("dblclick", function(c) {

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      width:400,
      height:250,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Remove Connection": function() {
          jsPlumb.detach(c);
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        close: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
});
```

When I click cancel or X symbol of window, I got `Maximum call stack size exceeded error` . First I was thinking that maybe my jquery-ui file is somehow wrong or conflict with other files such as jquery.js. But, I'm also using $().tooltip() function which is also jquery-ui method and it works fine. Furthermore, my function is not recursive. So what should I do to fix my problem?

When I comment `$(this).dialog("close");` statements, my problem solves but dialog box is not closed.

**Edit**

I have simplified my question. In the simplest form, when I click "X" (close button of window) , I still get same error:

```
 jsPlumb.bind("dblclick", function(c) {

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          width:400,
          height:250,
          modal: true    
        });
    });
```

Comment: You have something recursive thing going on.. A replicated fiddle would be much helpful to solve this...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao as you can see, in the function, there is'nt any recursive operation

Comment: Can you create the issue in fiddle?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, with all my respect why do you want a fiddle for such a small piece of code ? I asked it because I never create a fiddle before.

Comment: @zwlayer check if your reference in the page has just one or more, if there are more than on reference then sometimes this happens.

Comment: Well, because this issue might be specific to your requirement, since there are no reports having this issue faced by anyone else and simply closing `dialog` will not give such error. So I asked to replicate if possible.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thank you so much for your interest and sorry If I was a bit rude. Now, I've deleted `modal:true` statement inside dialog, and the error is gone. But I want to understand why this statement may cause such an error?

Comment: @zwlayer a quick solution is use `return false;` to stop the operation after closing.

Comment: @Jai you say that as an answer to my last comment ? I did not understand what do you mean?

Comment: @zwlayer i just wanted to confirm if you don't have so many script references in the DOM.

Comment: He said it as solution when you include your `close:` and `buttons:` piece of code inside `dialog`, just `return false`, but even am feeling strange on your issue. Cannot judge it unless knowing the structure of your project.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I'give my html css and js file regarding with this page, could you check it out please?

Comment: I would have but I have no knowledge on `JsPlumb` and `Meteor`, So I think I will not be of much help to you here..

Comment: @zwlayer sorry that doesn't help in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this and solved by removing

```
modal: true,
```

Solution found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33199170/6284848