# Maximum call stack size exceeded. In dialog open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my project I've a dialog that display two buttons (confirm and cancel) the action. But when this appears, if I move or I click on a button with a function associated with me cause this error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

**This is the function that display the dialog:**

```
displayConfirmMessageBox: function(title, message, messageButtons) {
    if(title == undefined || title == ''){
        title = "<No message>";
    }   
    if(message == undefined || message == ''){
        message = "<No message>";
    } 
    if(messageButtons == undefined){    
        messageButtons = {};
        messageButtons[EALang['close']] = function(){   
            jQuery("#message_box_confirm").dialog("close");
        };
    }

    jQuery("#message_box_confirm").dialog("destroy");
    jQuery("#message_box_confirm").remove();
    jQuery("body").append(
        "<div id='message_box_confirm' title='" + title + "'>" +
        "<p>" + message + "</p>" +
        "</div>"
    );    

    jQuery("#message_box_confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen      : false,
        modal         : true,
        resize        : "auto",
        width         : 400,
        height        : "auto",
        resizable     : false,
        buttons       : messageButtons,
        closeOnEscape : true
    });

    jQuery("#message_box_confirm").dialog("open"); 
    jQuery(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonset button").addClass('btn');
    jQuery("#message_box_confirm .ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
},
```

**and this is the function that call the `displayConfirmMessageBox`:**

```
var messageButtons = {};

messageButtons['OK'] = function(){
    conferma = true;
    BackendCalendar.completeAppointmentStore(conferma, successCallback, errorCallback);
};

messageButtons[EALang['cancel']] = function(){
    conferma = false;
    $('#message_box_confirm').dialog('close');
};

GeneralFunctions.displayMessageBox(
    EALang['delete_resource_confirmation'], 
    EALang['warning_resource'], 
    messageButtons
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There doesn't seems to be anything in your code that could throw such error. It's most likely some other part of your code. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gz46bpzs/)). You should look for a function which calls another function which calls yet another, and so on... until it reaches call stack limit.

Comment: How I can see what cause the error? 'Cause my file is big 2469 rows!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed with `modal: true` on `modal:false` (better way delete this parameter).

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to set modal property to false, you can override dialog module...

add below code to a **script file** and everything works well (**script file** should load after "jquery-ui.js")

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._createOverlay = function () {
if (!this.options.modal) {
    return;
}

var isOpening = true;
this._delay(function () {
    isOpening = false;
});

this.overlay = $("<div>")
    .addClass("ui-widget-overlay ui-front")
    .appendTo(this._appendTo());

this.document.data("ui-dialog-overlays",
    (this.document.data("ui-dialog-overlays") || 0) + 1);}
```

Comment: THIS WORK! I used the script using a if that I check jquery.ui is loaded